# VC-dimension of triangles in 2D space

Tags: cg.comp-geom, machine-learning, lg.learning, computational-geometry

I have been reading in multiple places (e.g. [1], section 4) that the VC-dimension of the class of triangles (in 2D space) is 7. 
The issue is that, for the case when 4 points lying on a straight line with alternating signs (like - + - +), I don't see why a triangle could separate the points. Where am I making mistake?

[1] http://www.igi.tugraz.at/lehre/CI/SS08/tutorials/VC_examples/VC_examples.pdf

Comment: You are getting the quantifiers in the definition of VC dimension wrong. The VC dimension being 7 means that *there exists* a set of 7 points that can be shattered and *no set* of 8 points can be shattered

Comment: I am confused now. The thing is I can always find a set of 8 points such that a triangle shatters it. Draw a triangle, put 4 points inside it, and four points outside it. Right?

Comment: @Daniel: Shattering means that you have to be able to separate *all* +/- labellings of the same set of points, I think.

Comment: @HuckBennett oh this makes sense now!

Comment: A personal pet peeve, from teaching this stuff for years... A triangle (or any single concept) does NOT shatter a set of points. Only a CLASS of concepts can shatter a set.

Comment: Do you think the answer I have written below is correct then?

Comment: I don't think this is a research level question, and therefore it probably doesn't belong on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sasho and Huck mentioned in their comments, "shattering means that you have to be able to separate all +/- labelings of the same set of points, given the function class."

Therefore, since the set of points on a line is never separable by the class of triangles, it is not a valid set of points to decide the VC-dimension this class.